# difference between wrapping EditText with TextInputLayout Vs wrapping TextInputEditText with TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-widget, android-xml, android-design-library

Want to know difference between

wrapping **EditText** with **TextInputLayout** *Vs* wrapping **TextInputEditText** with **TextInputLayout** ?. I tried using both, they worked same.
So which to use when ?

Searched on google but unable to find any

Comment: `EditText` is the legacy/first version of text input. `TextInputLayout` is meant to be used with `TextInputEditText` since they work together for some features - which `EditText` doesn't have. `TextInputEditText` is a subclass of `EditText`.

Comment: @TheLibrarian
"since they work together for some features - which EditText doesn't have" --
if possible can you provide some of its features which EditText doen't have ?. Just curious, want to try it.

Comment: "Using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputEditText) class allows us to display a hint in the IME when in 'extract' mode and provides accessibility support for TextInputLayout."